# import data into openshift mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, openshift

I created a java application on openshift with the mongoDb cartridge.
My application runs fine, both locally on jboss AS7 as on openshift.
So far so good.
Now I would like to import an csv into the mongoDb on the openshift cloud.
The command is fairly simple:

```
mongoimport -d dbName -c collectionName --type csv data.csv --headerline
```

This works fine locally, and I know how to connect to the openshift-shell and remote mongo-db. But my question is: how can I use a locally stored file (data.csv) when executing this commando in a ssh-shell.

I found [this](https://www.redhat.com/openshift/community/forums/express/importing-data-into-mongodb-on-express) on the openshift forum, but I don't realy know what this tmp directory is and how to use it.
I work on windows, so I use Cygwin as a shell-substitute.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tmp directory is shorthand for `/tmp`.  On Linux, it's a directory that is cleaned out whenever you restart the computer, so it's a good place for temporary files.

So, you could do something like:

```
$ rsync data.csv openshiftUsername@openshiftHostname:/tmp
$ ssh openshiftUsername@openshiftHostname
$ mongoimport -d dbName -c collectionName --type csv /tmp/data.csv --headerline
```

Comment: Thank you Kristina. I installed [rockMongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo) to administer the mongo instance and this also provides some import tools.

Comment: I would say use scp rather than rsync. You also need to specify --host on the mongoimport command. Use the environment variable --host $OPENSHIFT_NOSQL_DB_HOST. You will probably also need to use the username and password for the admin account on your MOngo instance. When I did the command tonight it looked like this:
mongoimport -d tbird -c parks --type json --file tbird/tmp/parkcoord.json  -h $OPENSHIFT_NOSQL_DB_HOST  -u admin -p XXXXXXXXX

Comment: As of 21.12.2013 you have to use $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST instead of $OPENSHIFT_NOSQL_DB_HOST

Answer (score 4):

This is what I needed in October 2014:

`mongoimport --host $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST --port $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT -u admin -p 123456789 -d dbName -c users /tmp/db.json`

Note that I used a json file instead of csv

Answer (score 3):

When using Openshift you must use the environment variables to ensure your values are always correct. Click here to read more about [Openshift Envrionment variables](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/page/openshift-environment-variables)

SSH into your openshift server then run ***(remember to change the bold bits in the command to match your values)***:

```
mongoimport --headerline --type csv \
    --host $OPENSHIFT_NOSQL_DB_HOST \
    --port $OPENSHIFT_NOSQL_DB_PORT \
    --db **your db name** \
    --collection **your collection name** \
    --username $OPENSHIFT_NOSQL_DB_USERNAME \
    --password $OPENSHIFT_NOSQL_DB_PASSWORD \
    --file ~/**your app name**/data/**your csv file name**
```

**NOTE**
When importing csv files using mongoimport the data is saved as strings and numbers **only**. It will **not** save arrays or objects. If you have arrays or object to be saved you must first convert your csv file into a proper json file and then mongoimport the json file.

Answer (score 1):

I installed [RockMongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo) on my openshift instance to manage the mongodb.
It's a nice userinterface, a bit like phpMyAdmin for mysql

Comment: Let me know if you get the import to work in RockMongo. I tried tonight and it was a no go. I did the scp, ssh, mongoimport route given above. 
Then again I used a JSON file not a CSV

Comment: sorry for the late response.
The import functionality in RockMongo didn't help me either. Eventualy I succeeded by converting the .csv to a json and import it using mongoimport

Answer (score 1):

Users who wish to use `mongorestore` the following worked for me:

First copy your dump using scp to the data dir on openshift:

```
scp yourfile.bson yourhex@yourappname.rhcloud.com:app-root/data
```

rhc ssh into your app and cd to the `app-root/data` folder.

```
mongorestore --host $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST 
--port $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT 
--username $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME 
--password $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD 
-d yourdb 
-c yourcollection 
yourfilename.bson --drop
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this!

Comment: @digita1-anal0g - Glad its useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Simon's answer, but this is how I imported `.json` to the database:

`mongoimport --host $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST -u admin -p 123456 --db dbname --collection grades < grades.json`